# checkbox in gridview in c# validation in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, gridview

I have a gridview With 2 ItemTemplates-
A checkBox,A TextBox
I have to Validate4 using Javascript
IF a checkbox is checked and qty is not written in the checkbox !!
 i have to inform the client What do i do?
The checkbox and the textbox are in the same row of the gridview as understood.
Plz Give me the script
Thankz in advance.

Comment: if the checkbox is checked the textbox can't have "qty" as text? I'm not sure if this is what you mean

Comment: NO,the checkbox and textbox are seperate itemtemplates in the same row of a gridview....if the texbox is checked text should be definetly typed in the checkbox

Comment: sorry text should be typed in the textbox for sure if the checkbox is checked

Comment: sounds like `in`ception.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) it can be done easily.
Create a function which will take "this" as parameter and on check box "Click" event pass "this" to the function. Then using .prev() method of jQuery you can get the "tr" row of the grid

```
 var trContainer = $(this).prev("tr")
```

Once you have the just do (using [jQuery find](http://api.jquery.com/find/))

//If you have only one text box in the row

```
 var txtBox = $(trContainer).find("input");
```

//If you have more than one text box

//Add some dummy css class to this textbox eg txtValidateClass

```
var txtBox = $(trContainer).find(".txtValidateClass");
```

Now once you have this textbox just check for

```
if($(txtBox).val().trim() == ""){
      //Show error
}else{
    //Continue
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Question is old but just in case someone else needs a solution that works only with JavaScript here is how.

### 1. C# Part (In `Page_Load` Method)

In `Page_Load` we need to add a small hack:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in YourGridViewControlID.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
    {
      ((CheckBox) row.FindControl("YourCheckBoxID")).Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:ShowErrorMessage(" + (row.RowIndex ) + ");");
    }
}
```

This way, we are adding the JavaScript function call on the `OnChange` event of every `CheckBox` of our `GridView`. What is special and we can't achieve through the `HTML` is that we are passing the `Row Index` of each one in the JavaScript function, something that we need later.

### 2. Some important notes for the HTML Part

Make sure that both `Checkbox` control and `Textbox` control but **more importantly** your `GridView` Control has static id by using the `ClientIDMode="Static"` as shown bellow:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="YourCheckBoxID" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="YourTextBoxID" TextMode="SingleLine" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

And for the `GridView` control:

```
<asp:GridView ID="YourGridViewControlID" ...... ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
```

### 3. Javascript Part

And then in your JavaScript file/code:

```
function ShowErrorMessage(Row) {
  // Get current "active" row of the GridView.
  var GridView = document.getElementById('YourGridViewControlID');
  var currentGridViewRow = GridView.rows[Row + 1];

  // Get the two controls of our interest.
  var rowTextBox = currentGridViewRow.cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  var rowCheckbox = currentGridViewRow.cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

  // If the clicked checkbox is unchecked.
  if( rowCheckbox.checked && rowTextBox.value === '') {
    // Empty textbox therefore show error message.
    return;
  }

  // Optionally hide the error message here.
}
```

### 4. Some Notes for the above implementation

- Note that in the JavaScript code, at the line:
  `var currentGridViewRow = GridView.rows[Row + 1];`
  the `[Row + 1]` is important to make this work and should not change.
- And finally:

The following lines:

```
var rowTextBox = currentGridViewRow.cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
var rowCheckbox = currentGridViewRow.cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
```

The `.cells[2]` and `.cells[0]` is maybe different for you, so you have to choose the correct number in the `[]`.
Usually, this will be the column number of your `GridView` starting counting from `0`.

So if your `CheckBox` was in the first column of the GridView then you need `.cells[0]`.
If your `TextBox` is in the second column of your `GridView` then you need `.cells[1]` (in my case above, `TextBox` was in the third column of my `GridView` and therefore, I used `.cells[2]`).

### 5. A small addition

The above is a code that works as the question owner have described the problem.

But I think that in this case is also a good idea to hide the error message when the a change has been made to the textbox. This is when the user check the checkbox and the textbox is empty, gets an error message then types something to the textbox and we should hide the error message.

In brief here are the additions for the above note (for simplicity I have removed the other code but you should keep both if you want to keep the entire functionality):

Here is the C# modification:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in YourGridViewControlID.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
    {
      ((TextBox) row.FindControl("YourTextBoxID")).Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "javascript:HideErrorMessage(" + (row.RowIndex ) + ");");
      ((TextBox) row.FindControl("YourTextBoxID")).Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:HideErrorMessage(" + (row.RowIndex ) + ");");
    }
}
```

As can be seen here, he have added the `onblur` event as well, as this one with the combination of the `onkeyup` we ensure that the code will be executed for all cases.

Here is the JavaScript modification:

```
function HideErrorMessage(Row) {
  // Get current "active" row of the GridView.
  var GridView = document.getElementById('YourGridViewControlID');
  var currentGridViewRow = GridView.rows[Row + 1];

  // Get the two controls of our interest.
  var rowTextBox = currentGridViewRow.cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  var rowCheckbox = currentGridViewRow.cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

  // If the clicked checkbox is unchecked.
  if( rowCheckbox.checked && rowTextBox.value !== '') {
    // Hide the error message here.
  }
}
```